# Wicked_PDF converting to wrong size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I have a html layout that is set to 
612px
792px
which should render as an 8.5 x 11 letter size page.

However when I render I come up with something smaller than the letter size.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Wkhtmltopdf's default page size is A4 by default.

Either add this to your render call:

```
render :pdf => 'my_file.pdf', :page_size => 'Letter'
```

Or, add it to config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb like so:

```
WickedPdf.config = { :page_size => 'Letter' }
```

for a application-wide change.